# Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2, overrides, email-templates, order-email, override-model

I am override the file sender.php this is not a normal class is abstract class may be that's the reason to display the error Could anyone suggest regarding this so i can proceed forward.

error
[image]

Comment: The error "cannot instantiate an interface" means that you are trying to create an instance of an interface directly, which is not allowed in PHP. Interfaces are not meant to be instantiated, but rather they define a set of methods that a class must implement.

Comment: Could you give me the path to the file you're trying to override, maybe I can help taking a closer look, thanks!

Comment: vendor\module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\Sender.php